# Blazor CSS not found

Tags: css, apache, proxy, blazor

When I execute my Blazor app on localhost everything is fine. When I upload the compiled code to my final server, the app works but all CSS/JS are missing.
I use Centos 7 + Apache in reverse proxy mode.
My CNF:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
# Your domain name
ServerName 192.168.5.69

ProxyPreserveHost On

# The IP and port of the JBoss Enterprise Application Platform
# These represent the default values, if your HTTPD is on the same host
# as your JBoss Enterprise Application Platform managed domain or server

ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/

# The location of the HTML files, and access control information
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:5000/$1 [P]

<Directory /var/www/html>
Options -Indexes
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

On Chrome console I see:

````
Siti:12 GET http://192.168.5.69/js/JavaScriptInterop.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Siti:11 GET http://192.168.5.69/css/site.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Siti:10 GET http://192.168.5.69/css/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)```
````

Comment: How do you publish the app exactly ?

Comment: Actually I am simply copying files via FTP.

Comment: You need do run `dotnet publish` and copy the publish folder

Comment: I've done `dotnet publish -c Release` on my dev PC and copied files to FTP but still I can't load CSS :-(

Comment: Which folder do you copy ? Is your `<base href>` well defined ?

Comment: I copy the content of bin\Relese\publish to my /var/www/html. Code is working, I can browse pages, add or remove entities.... but I can't load static files like js, css, ico. I don't have any base href tag.

Comment: Is your app hosted at `http://192.168.5.69`, or in sub folder ?

Comment: It's in the root, I've published it to www/html :-)

Comment: Did you try to add sub folders (js, css) in your proxy configuration ?

Comment: Now I am doing `ProxyPass /css/ http://localhost:5000/
ProxyPassReverse /css/ http://localhost:5000/
ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/`Funny thing, it started serving me js files but css still can't be served.